# How do I map 'i' to go to 'i' + other key combination?

Tags: vim

In gVimi 7.4, what I am trying to achieve is:

```
SampleText
```

When the cursor is at `m` of `SampleText` and I hit `i`, I want it to append a space and move left to one position. The desired result would be

```
Sa mpleText  (cursor will be after 'a').
```

I tried to map with following but couldn't get it to work. How can I achieve the desired result?

```
:nnoremap i i<space><left>
```

Comment: That worked as expected for me. Did you mean to remap `a` instead of `i`?

Comment: Really? hmmm I wonder why not for me? I meant that combo for 'i', for 'a' - I wanted to have sth like a<right><space>, but neither of these work for me.. Thank-you for testing that.

Comment: Maybe try `vim -u NONE -U NONE` to disable all vimrc stuff and debug it that way. Maybe space or left keys are remapped? noremap just deals with the first i, the second ones may be mapped I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should work as expected. I suggest you try some debugging:

1. Skip all initializations by invoking vim as:

   ```
   vim -u NONE -U NONE
   ```
2. Map your key:

   ```
   :nnoremap i i<space><left>
   ```
3. Check your mapping is good:

   ```
   :nnoremap i
   ```

   Should display something like:

   ```
   n  i           * i <Left>
   ```

   `nnoremap` disallows mapping of `{rhs}`, therefore there shouldn't be nested and recursive mappings.
4. Make sure you are indeed in the normal mode (not visual mode) by pressing
   `Esc`.
5. Test your mapping.